# Passing identically named arguments through nested functions

Tags: r, graphics, plot, arguments, radix

I am creating a simple plot which uses a plotting function, which calls another plotting function to add a smoothed line through it. The second function is `lines()` and takes some standard base graphics arguments. The first function also uses the same named argument. Now I would like to change some elements of the second plot without altering the first. I have at least a few options I can think of:

- Plot each seperately
- Rewrite the function to include uniquely named arguments to the second plotting function
- Make a new plot function for this maybe using ggplot2

And I got to thinking is it possible without rewriting anything, to pass through argument values to nested functions. Note in this question I am not asking for a function to do the plotting - I can write my own as necessry, I am asking if it is possible for me to specify in the arguments list to `traceplot` an argument that will only be passed to `lines` if it is also a named argument of traceplot. Example:

```
require(coda)
require(geoRglm)

# Some example data
mcmc <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

# Input parameters for mcmc object
input <- structure(list(S.scale = 3.75e-05, Htrunc = "default", S.start = "default", 
    burn.in = 0, thin = 100, n.iter = 20000, phi.start = 0, phi.scale = 1), .Names = c("S.scale", 
"Htrunc", "S.start", "burn.in", "thin", "n.iter", "phi.start", 
"phi.scale"), class = "mcmc.geoRglm")


# create mcmc object
mcmc_obj <- create.mcmc.coda( mcmc , mcmc.input = input )


#Plot - smooth = TRUE draws the smooth line through the data
traceplot( mcmc_obj , smooth = TRUE , main = "Default")


# Changing the colour argument passes the same argument through to the lines function called to plot the smooth line
traceplot( mcmc_obj , smooth = TRUE , col = 2 , main = "Change colour to red")
```

[image]

```
# In the source code of traceplot 'lines()' is called to plot the smooth line.
# Can I specify a colour argument to be passed only to lines without altering
# the function?
# Excerpt from the source code of traceplot:

function (x, smooth = FALSE, col = 1:6, type = "l", ylab = "", 
    ...) 
{
... some code here then...
if (smooth) {
            for (k in 1:nchain(x)) lines(lowess(xp, yp[, k]) 
        }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think there's a way to do this without changing the `traceplot` function.

Comment: @BenBolker I though that this might be the case, but I wanted to check because if there was it would be useful. I will probably just have to knock something simple up in ggplot2. Everyone just loves those grey backgrounds.

Comment: I don't, I always use `theme_set(theme_bw())` right after I load the package.  (You should check out `xyplot.mcmc` in the `coda` package and the `scapeMCMC` package ... the `scapeMCMC::plotTrace` function might do what you want with its `col.loess` vs. `col.trace` arguments ...

Comment: Your excerpt is bit misleading, the funtion call in for loop continues in next line, the whole call is `lines(lowess(xp, yp[, k]), col = scol[k])`, where `scol <- rep(col, length = nchain(x))`, so it's quite clear that you cannot alter the colors without changing the function (for example by adding argument `scol` and removing above definition). 
`

Comment: @Hemmo I missed the brace clsoing lines. I thought col was referring to a column placement or something. Still, as I pointed out, the semantics of the function aren't really the point of this question. Rewriting the function is as simple as adding an argument, say `lcol` to traceplot. The point of the question was to know if what I posited was possible.

Comment: Isn't there a way to pass a `par` config to one function and another `par` config to another function? We can plot like `plot(x,y,"col"="red")`, that is, name parameteres with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass different parameters by using two lists:

```
myfun <- function(x,y,par1=NULL,par2=NULL){
  if(is.null(par1)){
    plot(x,y)
  }else{
    do.call(plot,c(list(x=x,y=y),par1))
  }
  if(is.null(par2)){
    lines(x,y)
  }else{
    do.call(lines,c(list(x=x,y=y),par2))
  }
}
```

`par1` for params to `plot` and `par2` for params to `lines`. Then use `do.call` if you have such params:

```
myfun(1:10,1:10) # no params
myfun(1:10,1:10,par1=list(pch=20)) # params only to plot
myfun(1:10,1:10,par1=list(pch=20),par2=list(col="red",lwd=2)) # params to plot and lines
```